# How to scroll in HorizontalListView programmatically?

Tags: java, android, listview

I do new logic in the `HorizontalListView` class using the following:

```
private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        synchronized (HorizontalListView.this) {
            mDataChanged = true;
            int firstVisiblePos = HorizontalListView.this.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int lastVisiblePos = HorizontalListView.this.getLastVisiblePosition();
            Log.i(mTag, "firstVisiblePosl " + firstVisiblePos+ " lastVisiblePos  " + lastVisiblePos );
            if (mAdapter.getCount() > lastVisiblePos) {
                int sumTotal = 0;
                for (int i = firstVisiblePos; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    View child = HorizontalListView.this.getChildAt(i);
                    if (child != null) {
                        sumTotal += child.getWidth();
                    }
                }
                int sumPartial = 0;
                for (int i = lastVisiblePos; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    View child = HorizontalListView.this.getChildAt(i);
                    if (child != null) {
                        sumPartial += child.getWidth();
                    }
                }

                Log.i(mTag, "sumTotal " + sumTotal+ " sumPartial " + sumPartial);
                mScroller.startScroll(sumTotal, 0, sumPartial, 0);
            }
        }

        Log.i(mTag, " " + mCurrentX + "mNextX " + mNextX);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
```

but this has no effect: I want to scroll to left up to last item at mAdapter is visible.